# How to start a form after an async method returns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await

In this function (1st piece of code) i want to call the form DSXSettings.

It works in the `else` part, because there is no asynchronous method before, but when I want to start the form after the asynchronous Method, I get into a deadlock.

The function runs within a class of a tray application and the class is inheriting from ApplicationContext (2nd piece of code).

Unfortunatelly `BeginInvoke` is not implemented, as far as I know this could be a solution.

Is there an easy way to prevent the deadlock and get back to my UI thread?

**1st piece of code**

```
Private Async Sub InitDSXAutoGen()
    Try
        UserHandlingOK = _DSXUserHandling.GetUserAndPassword(_DSXConfig.GetKeys)

        If UserHandlingOK Then
            ConnectionOK = Await _DSXUserHandling.TestConnection(_DSXUserHandling.UserName, _DSXUserHandling.Password)
                If Not ConnectionOK Then
                    _DSXSettings = New DSXSettings(1)
                    _DSXSettings.Show()
                End If
        Else
            _DSXSettings = New DSXSettings(1)
            _DSXSettings.Show()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

**2nd piece of code**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace System.Windows.Forms
    Public Class ApplicationContext
    Implements IDisposable
        Public Sub New()
        Public Sub New(mainForm As Form)
        Public Property MainForm As Form
        Public Property Tag As Object
        Public Event ThreadExit As EventHandler
        Public Sub Dispose()
        Public Sub ExitThread()
        Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        Protected Overridable Sub ExitThreadCore()
        Protected Overridable Sub OnMainFormClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Can you clarify the deadlock?  Is it during `TestConnection`?  Which pieces are mutually blocked?

Comment: `Private Async Sub InitDSXAutoGen()` should be `Private Async Function InitDSXAutoGen() as Task`. You have to show what calls and awaits this method -- Why did you post the prototype of ApplicationContext and not your implementation? -- `BeginInvoke` is quite unrelated

Comment: ...But probably `Private Async Function InitDSXAutoGen() as Task(Of Boolean)`, since you shouldn't have that `ConnectionOK`, unclear where it's been declared. You should assign this Field (?) / Property (?) the value that the Function returns -- The If / Else condition could be simplified to avoid writing `_DSXSettings = New DSXSettings(1)` twice (`_DSXSettings` still declared somewhere else, should not be the responsibility of this method to new it) -- The empty `Catch` block is a red flag

Comment: @Craig the boolean value of TestConnection  ist coming as expected. The form starts to open, but you see the border of the form. Then the form freezes.

Comment: Is `TestConnection` itself supposed to produce a form?  If not, I don't see how you're having a problem with the `UserHandlingOK And Not ConnectionOK` branch vs. the `Not UserHandlingOK` branch.

Comment: @Craig Even when I try to produce the form at the end of my TestConnection, I have the same problem, but in this case I can understand it, because it's running within a class, outside my UI thread. I even tried to add ConfigureAwait(false) at the end of my TestConnection function, but without success.

Comment: @Craig I assume, the problem is caused by the fact, that the class where I call my TestConnection is not a form.

Comment: The problem is solved. Unbelievable for me, but when i use .ShowDialog instead of only .Show, the form opens correctly.